# Dependency Property issue within wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties

I have a wpf application, in which I'd like to bind inbindable property

```
      <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedDate="{Binding DateP, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
                                        <DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
                                                <CalendarDateRange   view:Facturation.End="{Binding DateE1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                                <CalendarDateRange   view:Facturation.Start="{Binding DateS1, Mode=TwoWay}"    view:Facturation.End="{Binding DateE2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                                        </DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
                                          </DatePicker>
```

In the code behind I added this snippet :

```
 public partial class Facturation : UserControl
{
    public Facturation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Start", typeof(DateTime), typeof(Facturation));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EndProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("End", typeof(DateTime), typeof(Facturation));



    public DateTime End
    {

        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(EndProperty); }

        set { SetValue(EndProperty, value); }

    }

    public DateTime Start
    {

        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(StartProperty); }

        set { SetValue(StartProperty, value); }

    }
}
```

When I launch the application I got this exception :

> Unable to set 'Binding' on property 'End' of type 'CalendarDateRange'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

**Edit**

Even I create a custom datepicker :

```
 class SpecialDatePicker: DatePicker
{
    public SpecialDatePicker()
    {

    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Start", typeof(DateTime), typeof(SpecialDatePicker));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EndProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("End", typeof(DateTime), typeof(SpecialDatePicker));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CalendarDateRangeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CalendarDateRange ", typeof(CalendarDateRange), typeof(SpecialDatePicker));


    public DateTime End
    {

        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(EndProperty); }

        set { SetValue(EndProperty, value); }

    }

    public DateTime Start
    {

        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(StartProperty); }

        set { SetValue(StartProperty, value); }

    }

    public CalendarDateRange CalendarDateRange
    {

        get { return (CalendarDateRange)GetValue(CalendarDateRangeProperty); }

        set { SetValue(CalendarDateRangeProperty, value); }

    }
}
```

and I change the xaml file like this :

```
  <skin:SpecialDatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectedDate="{Binding DateP, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}">
                                            <skin:SpecialDatePicker.BlackoutDates>
                                                <CalendarDateRange    End="{Binding DateE1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                                <CalendarDateRange    Start="{Binding DateS1, Mode=TwoWay}"     End="{Binding DateE2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                                        </skin:SpecialDatePicker.BlackoutDates>
```

I get the same result  .

**EDIT2**

As @Rachel said ,I just added this converter

```
 class DatesToBlackoutDateCollection : IMultiValueConverter 
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        CalendarBlackoutDatesCollection coll = new CalendarBlackoutDatesCollection(null);

        DateTime datDebut =(DateTime) values.Min() ;
         DateTime datFin =(DateTime) values.Max() ;

         coll.Add(new CalendarDateRange(datDebut,datFin));
        return coll;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (object[])value;
    }
}
```

in the Xaml File :

```
    <DatePicker.BlackoutDates>

                                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DatesToBlackoutDateCollection}">
                                                        <Binding Path="DateS1" />
                                                        <Binding Path="DateE2"/>
                                                    </MultiBinding>
 </DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
```

But no change, a similair exception appears .

I need to know :

1. What is the reason of this error?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: The reason is that `CalendarDateRange` is not inherited from `DependencyObject`

Comment: @dkozl How can I fix my code then

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use `.RegisterAttached` on your dependency property definition instead of `.Register`? I thought you could only attach a property to another object type if you used `.RegisterAttached`

Comment: @Rachel No I get the same exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object [`CalendarDateRange` does not inherit from DependencyObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendardaterange%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so it doesn't participate in WPF's binding system. This means you cannot bind any properties on it.

I would suggest binding the `BlackoutDates` property using an `IMultiValueConverter` to convert your dates to a [`CalendarBlackoutDatesCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendarblackoutdatescollection(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```
<DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DatesToBlackoutDateCollection}"> 
           <Binding Path="DateE1" />
           <Binding Path="DateS1"/>
     </MultiBinding>
 </DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
```

Alternatively, you could try making attached properties on the `DatePicker` object, and using code behind to transfer the data to the `DatePicker.BlackoutDates` property.

Comment: thanks, but I get an exception `Can not use a 'MultiBinding' in collection 'CalendarBlackoutDates Collection'. A 'MultiBinding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.` . Please take a look to my **EDIT2** part

Comment: @LamloumiAfif Ahh it sounds like the `BlackoutDates` property is not a DependencyProperty then. In that case, I'd recommend making an attached property for the `DatePicker` control and having the code transfer the bound values to the `BlackoutDates` collection then. A quick google search turned out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1638128/302677) which has some decent looking answers that would probably work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the reason for the error?

   - You can only bind to the dependency property. `CalendarDateRange` is not a dependency property.
2. How can I fix it?

   - Either extend the existing `DatePicker` control to create a custom DatePicker having the `CalendarDateRangeDependency` properties. Or Since you mention code behind, guessing your are not using MVVM pattern, simply assign the black out dates in the code behind.

Of course the recommended pattern is to create a custom DatePicker control with the dependency properties for black out dates.

**EDIT**

You could also create [attached](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx) dependency property and use it for your calendar black-out dates. 
I'll provide a code on how to do it with custom DatePicker control (more coding) if you want, otherwise , you could follow the attached property way (much simpler) as provided in other answer.

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate your idea about the extesnion of current datepicker , plz see my edit