# C# WPF, Datepicker validation

Tags: c#, wpf, validation

I'm trying to validate date in XAML using validation rules.

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <DatePicker Height="25"  x:Name="DatePickerDate">
        <DatePicker.SelectedDate>
            <Binding Path="ViewModel.Date" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <validationRules:DatePickerValidationRule/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </DatePicker.SelectedDate>
    </DatePicker>
</StackPanel>
```

And Validation rule

```
public class DatePickerValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var date = (DateTime) value;

        return date.Date.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 0
            ? new ValidationResult(false, "the date can not be before today")
            : new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

But when I put breakpoint into validation rule, it never goes there even if I change the Date.

Since I am new to WPF, it would be appreciable if any suggestions or guidance are available here.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2616392/773118) answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date picker validation WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610883/date-picker-validation-wpf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same problem and thought I should share my solution:

I had a static minimum date constraint so just specified BlackoutDates

```xml
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding StartDate}" Name="DepartureDate">
    <DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
        <CalendarDateRange Start="1/1/0001" End="12/31/1969"/>
    </DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
</DatePicker>
```

But if you need a more dynamic solution you could consider [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4416770/3076944).

Comment: No problem, I was posting for the poor dev that has to do this but doesn't know about the terribly documented/named BlackoutDates.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Save() function

```
this.DatePickerDate.SelectedDate = this.DatePickerDate.SelectedDate;
```

This should force the validation rule to validate