# Mark calendar blackout dates from context menu command

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am using MVVM and trying to mark the blackout dates of a calendar from its Calendar.ContextMenu using a command. I am trying to pass the calendar control as command parameter, but I am unsuccessful.
I would appreciate some help

Comment: Could you provide some code sample of the section in question?

Comment: You should not pass calendar on any other control to your viewmodel. neither trought command parameter. View is aware of viewmodel, therefore you may (and must) access viewmodel from view, but not vice versa. Calendar is a view (or part of view) and viewodel should not be aware of it

Comment: So how can I set blackout dates from the ViewModel?

Comment: In general, in viewmodel you should have something like public DateTime[] DisabledDates {get; set;} and you should databind it to calendar. If it is not possible to bind calendar to this property, there are some techniques how to do it

Answer (score 1):

That's bad MVVM, the ViewModel should not have any implementation knowledge of the UI. By passing a `UIElement` to the ViewModel you are breaking the pattern.

Instead, pass the `SelectedDate` as the command parameter and bind the `BlackoutDates` property to a collection of `DateTimes` in the ViewModel?

Comment: that's almost what I said in comments, but why the selected date as command parameter?

Comment: The ContextMenu item's purpose is to add a date to a set of blackout dates? Doesn't it make sense to pass the date the user has selected so that the ViewModel can add it to the blackout dates?

Comment: yes, you're right. I didn't get the ContextMenu item's purpose at first.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try that

Comment: How can I bind the BlackoutDates to a collection of DateTimes,  it only has start and end property which are DateTime, can you please give me an example, again thanks for your help

Comment: You can't bind directly to the BlackoutDates property, but can do so using an attached property. See [how-to-bind-blackout-days-in-wpf-toolkit-calendar-control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638128/how-to-bind-blackout-days-in-wpf-toolkit-calendar-control)