# To change datepicker loaded event in xaml.cs to viewmodel relay commands in xaml wpf (with mvvm pattern)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, viewmodel

i am trying to move the datepicker loaded event in xaml.cs to view model. I don't want the code behind in xaml.cs.

xaml code given below,

```
<DatePicker BorderBrush="LightBlue" BorderThickness="1" 
Name="dtTierValidTo"  IsEnabled="{Binding CanEdit}"
DisplayDateStart="{Binding TierDealValidFromDate, Mode=OneWay}"   
SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"  
DisplayDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded" >
   <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DtTierValidTo_Loaded}"
    PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
   </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DatePicker>
```

ViewModel.cs code is below..

```
public RelayCommand DtTierValidTo_Loaded { get; protected set; }
DtTierValidTo_Loaded = new RelayCommand(dtTierValidTo_Loaded); 

 private void dtTierValidTo_Loaded() 
{
 DatePicker dtTierValidTo =  new DatePicker();
//DatePicker dtTierValidTo = sender as DatePicker;
 dtTierValidTo.BlackoutDates.AddDatesInPast();
 }
```

But the the problem is, event is not getting triggered.

Could I get some help here

Comment: As per your requirement I got from code .Follow this link your task will be accomplished https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638128/how-to-bind-blackoutdates-in-wpf-toolkit-calendar-control

Comment: how can i attach that class to xaml. Sorry I am very new to WPF xaml MVVM

Comment: It will go into your main class behind the code . Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-register-an-attached-property

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DtTierValidTo_Loaded}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: sorry it is not working for me. is there any other simple way to achieve this

Comment: how can i pass sender object to relaycommand DtTierValidTo_Loaded